# Would like to learn SAP Business One development and to use the SDK

Tags: sdk, sapb1

I would like to know how to code for SAP B1 but where do I start and I would like a simple explanation. Ideally in VB.net.

Comment: Your question is very broad, but Sawsine has given you a good tip - go and find the Samples and the Help file for the SDK.  All the basics are in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SAP and the SDK installed Samples can be found here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One SDK\Samples\COM DI\VB.NET
```

a simple piece of DI-API Code to update a Sales opportunity might look like this:

```
        Private Function updateOpportunity(docEntry, type, value) As Boolean

        'updates either interest or status on linked opportunity
        'returns true if successful
        Dim oCompany As SAPbobsCOM.Company = Application.SBO_Application.Company.GetDICompany
        Dim oppToUpdate As SAPbobsCOM.SalesOpportunities = oCompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oSalesOpportunities)

        oppToUpdate.GetByKey(docEntry)

        If type = "Interest" Then
            oppToUpdate.InterestLevel = value
        ElseIf type = "Status" Then
            oppToUpdate.Status = value
        End If

        If oppToUpdate.Update() <> 0 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If

    End Function
```

and here a simple example to add lines to a sales order:

```
 Try

   Dim objCompany As SAPbobsCOM.Company = CType(Application.SBO_Application.Company.GetDICompany, SAPbobsCOM.Company)
    
                    objOrder = CType(objCompany.GetBusinessObject(docType), SAPbobsCOM.Documents)
                    objOrder.GetByKey(123456)           
                        'Add Rows     
                    With objOrder.Lines             

                            'adds a blank row to order
                            .Add()

                            'insert all the data
                            .ItemCode = "myItemCode"
                            .Quantity = 20
                            .UnitPrice = 2.50 

                    'save changes / test success 
                   dim intResult = CByte(objOrder.Update())    
            
                    If intResult = 0 Then
                       Application.SBO_Application.SetStatusBarMessage("Rows Added Successfully", SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Short, False)                    
                    End If
                 
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Application.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Add lines Failed  " & objCompany.GetLastErrorDescription)
                End Try
           
        End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. Was wondering if you can go into line items and add a line like in this case sales order.

Comment: no problem, i have added an example for sales order add lines. if you found it helpful please  accept the answer :)

Comment: I appreciate all your help, but now I am wondering do you have experience with document printing? I have a side project where I want from a grid to select or even a query based on docnum to print regardless if open, printed, etc....